# Why does `asyncio.run()` never return in Python 3.8?

Tags: python, exception, python-asyncio, cancellation

My application has the following top-level code (slightly abbreviated):

```
def main():
    # Some setup code ...
    try:
        asyncio.run(my_coroutine())
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exiting due to exception {}: {}".format(type(e).__name__, e))
    print("Coroutine finished")
    # Some cleanup code ...
    print("Shutdown complete")
```

In Python 3.8 `asyncio.run` never finishes, so the cleanup code does not run (and the shutdown text isn't printed). When the application is supposed to be exiting, it just hangs forever. In Python 3.7 it worked fine. Python 3.6 didn't have `asyncio.run`, but fairly similar code with `loop.run_until_complete()` and `loop.close()` also worked.

Some extra context: The setup and cleanup code starts and gracefully exits a worker thread created with [`threading.Thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread). It's this thread that actually stops the main coroutine: it cancels the coroutine (technically, it cancels another coroutine which is called within `my_coroutine()`) using [`loop.call_soon_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.call_soon_threadsafe)

Answer (score 6):

The premise of the question is wrong. (I knew that when I wrote it but not when I originally had the problem, so I left it in this form for others with the same problem.) `asyncio.run()` *is* finishing, but jumping over all the exception handling and shutdown code:

```
def main():
    # Some setup code ...
    try:
        asyncio.run(my_coroutine())
    except Exception as e:
        # <---- In Python 3.7, control passed to here when asyncio.run() finshed
        print("Exiting due to exception {}: {}".format(type(e).__name__, e))
    print("Coroutine finished")
    # Some cleanup code ...
    print("Shutdown complete")
    # <---- In Python 3.8 it directly dropped out of here!
```

This is because, in Python 3.8, the base class of [`asyncio.CancelledError`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/asyncio-exceptions.html#asyncio.CancelledError) changed from `Exception` to `BaseException` (which is the base class of `Exception`). This was done to avoid mistakes within async code where people were catching `Exception` thinking that it meant some operation had failed (e.g. network error) but accidentally preventing cancellation; see [Python issue 32528](https://bugs.python.org/issue32528).

The application then failed to exit because Python waits for all threads to finish unless they are started with `daemon=False` passed to the `Thread` constructor (see the discussion a few paragraphs into [Thread objects docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects)). In my case, the thread is not a daemon thread (because I do want it to finish gracefully) but it will not exit unless I have requested it to, which is done in code where I put the comment "Some cleanup code...".

The solution is either to catch `asyncio.CancelledError` explicitly in addition to `Exception`, or use a `finally:` block instead. The `finally:` block is probably better since it really guarantees the code will be run, even in the face of other exceptions derived from `BaseException` such as `KeyboardInterrupt`:

```
def main():
    # Some setup code ...
    try:
        asyncio.run(my_coroutine())
    finally:
        print("Coroutine finished")
        # Some cleanup code ...
        print("Shutdown complete")
```

Comment: I have this problem and didn't understand it, how do you get asyncio.run to exit? without cancelled exception
`asyncio.run(asyncio.sleep(3)) #never returns`

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Rainb If your coroutine is liable to exit with a cancellation exception, then wrap it in an outer couroutine that has a `try:` / `except CancelledError:` block. But it makes little difference to wrapping `asyncio.run(...)` in the same block. Nowadays I use [Trio](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) instead of asyncio, which handles cancellation much more easily with [nurseries](https://vorpus.org/blog/timeouts-and-cancellation-for-humans/)

Comment: @RyanGlenn Who is your question aimed at - me or Rainb? I was satisfied with my own answer (!) so as far as I'm concerned there's nothing to figure out. For Rainb's question, see my other comment.

Comment: Actually [Nurseries & Spawning](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference-core.html#nurseries-and-spawning) in the Trio docs is a better link for Trio nurseries. I now use Trio for the application that originally made me post this question and answer, so no longer have to worry about `CancelledError` leaking out of my main coroutine.